# How to display random custom html widget within a widget area?

Tags: php, wordpress, random, widget

I've registered a new widget area in functions.php using

```
        'name' => __( 'Grand angle sous les articles', 'twentyten' ),
        'id' => 'grand-angle',
        'description' => __( 'Grand angle en bas des articles', 'twentyten' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="grand-angle">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
```

I'm calling this new widget area in a php template like this :

`<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'grand-angle' ) ) : dynamic_sidebar( 'grand-angle' ); endif; ?>`

Inside this new widget area I'm now adding several custom html widgets and I would like to display them randomly. These custom html widgets contain ads (mostly images) and I need to set up a rotation. Any idea how to do that? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found :

```
    add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'custom_randomize_widget_order' );

function custom_randomize_widget_order( $sidebars_widgets ) {
    $sidebars = array( 'grand-angle' ); // set the ids of your sidebars whose widgets you want to shuffle

    foreach ( $sidebars as $sidebar ) {
        if ( isset( $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ] ) && ! is_admin() ) {
            shuffle( $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ] );
            // Slice the array:
            $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ] = array_slice( $sidebars_widgets[ $sidebar ], 0, 1 );
        }
    }

    return $sidebars_widgets;
}
```